# Using variables vs SQL Server in using statement

Tags: c#, sql, variables, logic

Can someone help me understand what's happening? I'm trying to get the

1. SAQA ID
2. NQF Level
3. Credits

of a course but there's something I don't understand.

If I create a variable with my query such as

```
public Int32 T_Course_Id = 0, T_Company_Id = 0, T_Nqf = 0, T_Credit = 0;

string queryTaskId = "SELECT [course_saqa_id] FROM"+
                     "[sta].[dbo].[Courses]"+
                     "WHERE course_name = '" + _Coursename + "'";

string queryNqf = "SELECT [course_nqf]"+
                  "FROM [sta].[dbo].[Courses]"+
                  "WHERE course_saqa_id = '" + T_Course_Id + "'";

using (SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
{
    Conn.Open();

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryTaskId, Conn))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                reader.Read();
                // Call Read before accessing data. 
                T_Course_Id = reader.GetInt32(0);
            }

            // Call Close when done reading.
            reader.Close();
        }
    }

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryCredit, Conn))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                reader.Read();

               // Call Read before accessing data. 
                T_Credit = reader.GetInt32(0);
            }

            // Call Close when done reading.
            reader.Close();
        }
    }                    

    Conn.Close();
}
```

If I do it this way I get a 0 value for the `T_Credit` variable, but if I do it like this (this is only the last part)

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT [course_nqf] FROM [sta].[dbo].[Courses] WHERE course_saqa_id = '" + T_Course_Id + "'", Conn))
{
    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            reader.Read();
            // Call Read before accessing data. 
            T_Credit = reader.GetInt32(0);
        }

        // Call Close when done reading.
        reader.Close();
    }
 }
```

then I get the correct value, as you can see I'm passing the SQL command directly instead of a variable

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT [course_nqf] FROM [sta].[dbo].[Courses] WHERE course_saqa_id = '" + T_Course_Id + "'", Conn))
```

Why won't a variable work here ?

Comment: Have you tried using template strings? C# 6

Moreover, why are you calling close when you're already using the `using() { ... }` style?

Comment: It looks it's just a typo, you are using the wrong variable in your first case. You should use `queryNqf` instead of `queryCredit`.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: It would also be helpful to have some **spaces** between your keyword, if you concatenate together your SQL statement like that..... e.g. use `"SELECT [course_saqa_id] FROM " + "[sta].[dbo].[Courses]" + " WHERE course_name = @CourseName";` - note the **SPACE** after the `FROM` and before the `WHERE` keywords ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Order of operations matters.

**In your first example:**
You are setting the value of your `T_Course_ID = 0`, then creating a query string immediately after.  At that time, the `T_Course_ID` value is evaluated to `0` and forgotten.  The string concatenation IS NOT evaluated each time it is used.  ONLY at assignment.

**In your second example:**
`T_Course_ID` is assigned a new value by your initial lookup. Since the `SQLCommand` is executed after the variable reassignment, it is evaluated using the new value every time.

Here is an example using javascript, the same applies there was well:

```js
var T_Course_Id = 0;

var queryNqf =
  "SELECT [course_nqf]" +
  "FROM [sta].[dbo].[Courses]" +
  "WHERE course_saqa_id = '" + T_Course_Id + "'";

// Query displays initialized value
console.log(queryNqf);

// Variable is changed
T_Course_Id = 'I Will NOT CHANGE';

// Try to log the updated value but it doesn't work because queryNqf was assigned too early
console.log(queryNqf);

// Reassign with the new value
queryNqf =
  "SELECT [course_nqf]" +
  "FROM [sta].[dbo].[Courses]" +
  "WHERE course_saqa_id = '" + T_Course_Id + "'";

// Retrieve the expect result.
console.log(queryNqf);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not using the correct command string, queryNqf in your using statement.

**Yours**: using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(*queryCredit*, Conn))

**Could Be**:  using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(*queryNqf* , Conn))